# How do I turn a list of words into a flattened list of characters in C#?

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of `string` like this:

`List<string> KeyList=["AD","B","KT"]`

I want to split each item in the list in such a way where the final list output is a list of strings with only 1 character.

e.g.

`["A","D","B","K","T"]`

I have tried doing `KeyList.ToCharArray()` but that does not work.

Comment: Have you tried anything? please show us your attempt

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: You need to iterate over each element in the array and then use ToCharArray()

Comment: `list KeyList=["AD","B","KT"]` - that's not valid C#. Please provide *real* code (with what you've tried) rather than pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Select` LINQ extension method to turn each string into a list of 1-character strings, then flatten the list with `SelectMany`:

```
var list = new List<string>{ "AB", "B", "KT" };

var newList = list.SelectMany(s => s.Select(c => new string(c, 1))).ToList();
```

Comment: Why not use `ToCharArray` instead of `new string(c, 1)` ?

Comment: @AnuViswan OP used double-quotes for the desired output list in the question, I assumed the intention was to end up with a list of strings rather than a list of `char`'s :-)